# Comparing effect size for regression coefficients for models with different dependent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, model-comparison

I want to compare the regression coefficients $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{3}$ in the two models which have the same independent variables but slightly different dependent variables:
$$
\Delta{y}_{1}=\alpha +\beta_{1}X_{1} +\beta_{2}X_{2}+\varepsilon,
$$
$$
\Delta{y}_{2}=\alpha +\beta_{3}X_{1} +\beta_{4}X_{2}+\varepsilon.
$$

Here, $\Delta{y}_{1}$ and $\Delta{y}_{2}$ can be generically considered as growth rates, however, $\Delta{y}_{2}$ has a much greater variance than its counterpart.

How can I compare my variable of interest, $X_{1}$, between these two models? I could standardize the dependent variables before I run the models but I would like to know if there is a way to compare them after the regressions have already been run.